# Lightning Component doinit error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Not able to call doinit function from another controller method.I always get error doinit is undefined.Can we call doinit from another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The controller's "this" is undefined, so you cannot access anything in the controller. Methods that are shared should be put in the helper file and called from there. This is the purpose of the helper file.

Comment: This is something that I presume irritates just about everyone: do you know why this limitation is necessary i.e. what forces it to be the case?

Comment: @KeithC I don't think we're told "why," but from a performance perspective, helpers are shared resources while controllers are not, so having too much logic in the controller harms performance memory-wise. Blogs like [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/understanding-javascript-controllers-versus-helpers-lightning-components.html) say that we should use helpers as much as possible, and specifically call out " Anytime you need to call one controller function from another controller function, move that logic to Helper."

Comment: I have 3 controller functions.first 2 functions are working fine and in third function it is throwing error "helper.testingmethod() is not a function
"

Comment: @DebarunSengupta We would need to see some code to go with that error, but if your helper were written correctly, it would work.

Comment: test: function(cmp,event,helper)
    {
      debugger;
     var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": "https://latamdev-latamdev.cs30.force.com/portalphysician/s/medicationaccesssupport",
        "isredirect" :false
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
    helper.hello(cmp,event);
        
    }  like this I have test 1 and test2 but in test2 calling I am getting above error